# Driving in North and South Carolina with an Indian driving licence?

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, driving-licenses, south-carolina, north-carolina

I am a visitor in Charlotte, NC, and am planning to drive from Charlotte to Charleston by renting a car.

Will my Indian driving licence be enough for driving a car in the states of NC and SC, or do I need an international driver's permit?  I'd appreciate a source for any information, especially if forms are required to complete.

Comment: Welcome! Have you googled for any of this? Also, please see the [help], generally asking more than one question per post is considered too broad, if you can make it more specific.

Comment: @MarkMayo I'd say that the questions are sufficiently closely related to count as one question, unless you're suggesting it should be split by state. I don't think it makes sense to demand separate questions just because the asker was more specific than "What does somebody with an Indian driving license need to do to drive in NC and SC?"

Comment: @DavidRicherby I didn't vote to close or demand anything, just pointing out that often questions here get closed for such, and it's easier to edit it now before that happens.

Comment: @MarkMayo Yeah, I shouldn't have said "demand" but the comment's just too old to edit, now. But, still, I don't think "Some people might unreasonably request that you split your question so you should consider splitting it now to pre-empt their unreasonable request" is very helpful advice. It just legitimizes the unreasonable request and, at the end of the day, there's not a whole lot of difference between "I think other people will think you should do X so you should consider doing it" and "I think you should do X".

Comment: Fair enough, I was typing fast on the app.  I don't know if it's unreasonable - that's up to the community to decide, to be fair.  I might do some editing now that I'm on my computer to aid a bit.

Comment: See also *[Are international driving licences really necessary for any country?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/441)* and *[Can I drive in North-Carolina with a EU drivers license?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/31091)*, and *[Is Greek driver's license valid in the US?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19734)*. The answer is the same: yes, you can drive in the U.S. with a valid driver's license from a foreign government, and yes, an IDP is recommended if the license is not in English.

Comment: Finally i have rented a car with my Indian driving licence with no issues :)

Answer (score 2):

A quick google led me to [this webpage](http://www.usa.gov/Topics/Foreign-Visitors-Driving.shtml). It says you need to check the driving rules for the states you are going to, but it also says you should get an International Driving Permit before you arrive.

I got one of these before I went to the US to study for a year, but I am pretty sure my parents didn't bother when they came to the US and hired a car. That said, we are from the UK so our licenses are in English.

Comment: Indian Licences are in English too, but these depend on pairs of countries, Indian licence would work in UK for 6 months and in EU too

Comment: @skv - I wasn't sure if Indian Licenses would be in English or not, so thought I would just put the English bit in for clarity. People from other countries may read my answer too, so it may help them :)